# PHP - Code is saving incorrect data

Tags: php, session

I am making a login script. So what I have in my login.php is

```
           foreach ($json_decoded->response->players as $player)
            {

                  $_SESSION["steamid"] = "$player->steamid";
                  $_SESSION["steamname"] = "$player->pesonaname";
                  $_SESSION["profileurl"] = "$player->profileurl";
                  $_SESSION["profileimg"] = "$player->avatarmedium";

                }
```

the json has the required information but instead of saving the information, the script saves the `$player->pesonaname` instead. I tried writing the information to a file and it worked, with the needed info inside but it doesn't work when I'm saving it to $_SESSION. My coding is most likely wrong although I ripped it off of Google. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Remove the quotes from the right side of the assignments. It will resolve the problem.

Comment: If I do that it doesn't save anything to session at all.

Comment: Have you tried accessing $player as an associative array? $player['pesonaname']